# Suitable verse to recite to pretend to be a Muslim

Tags: non-muslim

If someone tries to seriously investigate whether I'm a Muslim or not, such as by asking for the [name of Mohammed's mother](http://zeenews.india.com/news/world/kenya-terror-attack-indian-killed-as-he-couldnt-name-prophet-muhammads-mother_878534.html), then the ruse will be up, but what's a suitable verse to recite to pretend to be a Muslim?

Ideally, the verse should not exist in the Bible or Talmud, should be a verse agreeable to Sunni Muslims, not be smart-alec-y (eg quoting something about how violence is wrong), and be reasonably easy for an English-speaker to pronounce correctly.

Comment: to *pretend* to be muslim? for what reason?

Comment: @muslim1 if someone's killing the non-Muslims and sparing the Muslims.

Comment: Memorize a few Surah including the most known one, Alfitaha. Also FYI terrorists even kill Muslims, which is why they are terrorists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this question is for dire circumstances and in that case no verse of the Quran could possible be convincing enough. If the intention is survival, then the best bet is to read the declaration of faith.

Ashadu an la ilaha illallah wa ashadu anna muhammadan rasulullah.

[I bear witness that there is no god worthy of worship except Allah and i bear witness that Muhammad is his servant and messenger]

This should paralyze the inquisition-ers  - in theory at least - if there is even an iota of understanding of Islam in them. Then again, you wouldn't have been in the quagmire in the first place if that were so. This should work because no Muslim has the permission, means or authority to adjudge the intentions and what hides inside the heart.

> O ye who believe! When ye go abroad in the cause of Allah, investigate
>   carefully, and say not to any one who offers you a salutation: "Thou
>   art none of a believer!" Coveting the perishable goods of this life:
>   with Allah are profits and spoils abundant. Even thus were ye
>   yourselves before, till Allah conferred on you His favours: Therefore
>   carefully investigate. For Allah is well aware of all that ye do. ([4:94](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.yusufali/4:94))

This is the advice, in principle, that Maimonides gave to the Spanish Jews facing inquisition at the hands of the Al-Moravid dynasty, i.e. accept Islam apparently.

Comment: Many terrorists now a days won't just do that, they would ask you to recite Quran as many have informed us happened.

Comment: If the ayah is not enough to demonstrate the seriousness of this in Islam, there is a hadith relating to a battle, that I will paraphrase from memory. One of the Companions of Muhammad fought someone who ran away, then turned around and proclaimed the muslim declaration of faith. The Companion (I think it was Umar) cut him down, assuming the enemy was just trying to save his life. After the battle, Muhammad heard about this and wouldn't stop berating the Companion with "Why did you kill him? Why did you kill him?"

Comment: The gist of it is, even in a battle situation, the shahada makes you muslim in exoteric terms, i.e. as relates to law, and you are to be allowed the rights of a muslim. Side note: I don't think the Companion was punished for it, but I assume that was because the ruling wasn't clear at the time he killed the man.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, best chapter to learn is sura al-fathiha first chapter of Quran. it is short with only 7 verses. All Muslims should know this chapter because it is obligatory to be recited in prayer. A Muslim need not know any other chapter and still be a Muslim. Additionally, there are  short chapters in the end of Quran (chapter 108 to 114). Learning and reciting them fluently can convince them more.

But it is not only verses they can ask for but other elementary things which all Muslims know. like how many daily prayers are there, how many raka'ath(units in prayer) are there for each prayer etc. So it would be required to have basic knowledge of all essential things in Islam.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest the Throne Vers, Sura 2, Vers 255  called -Ayat-ul-Kursi- as this Vers is described to be the most glorious Verse in the Qur'an.

When recited from the heart (means you know what you are saying) it protects the reciter and keeps him safe.

So if you recite it loudly, it will convince the one who questiones you that you know the Qur'an and at the same time you will be protected, inshaAllah.

Here is one of many stories how Ayat-ul-Kursi protected the reciter.

> Benefits of the Ayat-ul-Kursi
>
> It was reported in a local paper in Rochdale, of a young woman who was
>   raped in a small dark alley one evening.
>
> On a separate evening around the same time, a young Muslim woman was
>   walking home from college. Aware that it was getting dark fast, she
>   wanted to get home as soon as possible, so her mother would not worry
>   about her being outside alone at night.
>
> The young Muslim girl faced a dilemma. To take the short cut down the
>   same alleyway to avoid getting home after dark, or to take the longer
>   route and have her mother worrying herself sick about her safety.
>
> Conscious of the time, she took the alleyway. While the girl was
>   walking down the alley, she saw a rather sinister,
>
> threateningly dark figure of a man walking towards her from the other
>   end.
>
> As her pace quickened, she began to read Ayat-ul-kursi for her safety.
>
> On passing, the man made eye contact, but carried on walking.
>
> When the young Muslim girl reached home she told her family about this
>   sinister looking man. They advised her to contact the police, having
>   read the newspaper article some time before.
>
> When she contacted the police, they asked her to give a physical
>   description of the man. It matched the description the rape victim had
>   already given.
>
> Some days later the young Muslim girl received a phone call from the
>   police, asking her if she would go to the police station to identify
>   the man in a ‘line up’. Both the rape victim and the Muslim girl
>   picked out the same man. The police were confused though; they asked
>   the rapist why he had attacked one girl and not the other.
>
> With reference to the Muslim girl, he replied: 'Why would I attack her
>   when she had two huge men walking on either side of her?'

On http://quranexplorer.com/Quran/ you can listen to the Verse and read the translation as well.

Transliteration is here:

> Bismillahir Rahmanir Raheem
>
> ALLAAHUH LAA ILAAHA ILLAA HUWA HAYYUL QAYYOOMO, LAA TAAKHUZUHU
>   SINATUN WALAA NAUM, LAHU MAA FIS SAMAAWAATE WA MAA FIL ARZ, MAN ZAL
>   LAZE YASH-FA-U' I'NDAHU ILLAA BE-IZNIH, YA'LAMU MAA BAYNA AYDEEHIM WA
>   MAA KHALFAHUM, WA LAA YOHEETOONA BE SHAYIM MIN I'LMEHI ILLAA BEMAA
>   SHAAA-A, WASE-A' KURSIYYUHU SAMAAWAATE WAL ARZ, WA LAA YA-OODOHU
>   HIFZUHUMAA, WA HUWAL A'LIYYUL A'ZEEM.

May Allah keep you always safe.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but the story given is a bit in poor taste IMO.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such verse in Qur'an.

From story, there is Imam Ali story who stop swing his sword to his enemy, since that enemy says "Ashadu an la ilaha illallah wa ashadu anna muhammadan rasulullah."

Rasulullah only laugh when he hear this story which indicate his happiness.

Off course this "strategy" only work to people like Ali which is knowledgeable and NOT teroris :-P